# cause of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from an API. The below code "works" when I log the results to console like `console.log(liveInfo.tracks)`, but when I try to do `console.log(liveInfo.tracks.current)` it fails with this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')`. Isn't `liveInfo.tracks.current` how one would normally access the key-value pair?

```
componentDidMount() {
 fetch('https://kchungradio.airtime.pro/api/live-info-v2')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(
  (result) => {
   this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    liveInfo: result 
   })
  }
 )
}
```

The json looks more or less like this:

```
{
 "station": {
  "env": "production",
 },
 "tracks": {
  "previous": {
   "name": "a",
   "metadata": {
    "id": 1,
   },
  },
  "current": {
   "name": "b",
   "metadata": {
    "id": 2,
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Look at where you define your state and think about what your component does before you get a response back from the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you are trying to access to the `current` before it is filled on the `componentDidMount`, it means before the fetch has been performed. I suggest you to initialize the state like this:

```
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    liveInfo: {
      tracks: {
        curent: {}
      }
    }
  };
```

So you will be able to access the `current` property inside `tracks` without facing the `TypeError`. I made a codesandbox, so you can check an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-worker-w6ov49?file=/src/App.js) there.

If this does not solve your problem, please let me know ;)

Comment: see, i was under the impression that all the children were included in the response. didn't know i had to manually "set" the properties. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Because at some point `liveInfo.tracks` was `undefined`

Although there is a lack of hints, a common mistake when fetching data from lifecycle is trying to retrieve the value through the state before setData occurs.
Before you use `liveInfo`, make sure that data fetching is finished

like this

```
class SomeComponent = {
render() {
if(!this.state.liveInfo?.tracks?.current) return null
....
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call looks right,
another way to get the value is `console.log(liveInfo.tracks["current"]);`

but I think your tracks has no value at runtime. Maybe you can show us more code where you are call console.log.

Maybe you run twice in your statement and at first time it is undefined and throw the error. So add a null check like this `console.log(liveInfo?.tracks?.current);`

Answer (score 0):

Use Question mark (?)
? will check for null. If your object is null ? will handle it.

```
liveInfo?.tracks?.current
```

this is the right approach.

Further -

```
liveInfo?.tracks?.current?.metadata
```